# AVR Interrupt: LED kept blinking and won't stop

Tags: microcontroller, led, avr, interrupts

Lately I realize I am still a newbie, when you can't blink a freaking LED properly. It's kinda sad. I try to simplify this LED code to the simplest form possible, and it still won't work properly. Surely I can use the _delay_ms(); thing to blink a LED, but I really want to learn how to use interrupt instead, so here we go. The code below should have been stopped blinking that freaking LED after 5 iterations, but I had pressed the reset button, and I had compiled this code many times and re-uploaded it, but still, it just kept blinking NON-STOP!!!

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile uint8_t c=0;

int main(void){

    TCCR0B= (1<<CS02) | (1<<CS00);
    TIMSK0= (1<<TOIE0);
    sei();
    DDRD= 1<<1;
    //cli(); NO led flashing if this line is turned ON;

    while (1){
        if( c>5 ) { cli(); }
    }
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
    c++;
    PORTD ^= 1<<1;
}
```

Here is the LSS file, and yes, I read through it many times. I don't see what is the freaking problem is.

```
Interrupt.elf:     file format elf32-avr

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         000000a4  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .bss          00000001  00800100  00800100  00000118  2**0
                  ALLOC
  2 .comment      00000030  00000000  00000000  00000118  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  3 .debug_aranges 00000028  00000000  00000000  00000148  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  4 .debug_info   000000b0  00000000  00000000  00000170  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  5 .debug_abbrev 0000007f  00000000  00000000  00000220  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  6 .debug_line   000000cb  00000000  00000000  0000029f  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  7 .debug_frame  00000048  00000000  00000000  0000036c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  8 .debug_str    00000145  00000000  00000000  000003b4  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  9 .debug_loc    00000049  00000000  00000000  000004f9  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 10 .debug_ranges 00000018  00000000  00000000  00000542  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   19 c0           rjmp    .+50        ; 0x34 <__ctors_end>
   2:   28 c0           rjmp    .+80        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
   4:   27 c0           rjmp    .+78        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
   6:   26 c0           rjmp    .+76        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
   8:   25 c0           rjmp    .+74        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
   a:   24 c0           rjmp    .+72        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
   c:   23 c0           rjmp    .+70        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
   e:   22 c0           rjmp    .+68        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  10:   21 c0           rjmp    .+66        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  12:   20 c0           rjmp    .+64        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  14:   1f c0           rjmp    .+62        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  16:   1e c0           rjmp    .+60        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  18:   1d c0           rjmp    .+58        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  1a:   1c c0           rjmp    .+56        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  1c:   1b c0           rjmp    .+54        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  1e:   1a c0           rjmp    .+52        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  20:   28 c0           rjmp    .+80        ; 0x72 <__vector_16>
  22:   18 c0           rjmp    .+48        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  24:   17 c0           rjmp    .+46        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  26:   16 c0           rjmp    .+44        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  28:   15 c0           rjmp    .+42        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  2a:   14 c0           rjmp    .+40        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  2c:   13 c0           rjmp    .+38        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  2e:   12 c0           rjmp    .+36        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  30:   11 c0           rjmp    .+34        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>
  32:   10 c0           rjmp    .+32        ; 0x54 <__bad_interrupt>

00000034 <__ctors_end>:
  34:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  36:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  38:   cf ef           ldi r28, 0xFF   ; 255
  3a:   d4 e0           ldi r29, 0x04   ; 4
  3c:   de bf           out 0x3e, r29   ; 62
  3e:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61

00000040 <__do_clear_bss>:
  40:   21 e0           ldi r18, 0x01   ; 1
  42:   a0 e0           ldi r26, 0x00   ; 0
  44:   b1 e0           ldi r27, 0x01   ; 1
  46:   01 c0           rjmp    .+2         ; 0x4a <.do_clear_bss_start>

00000048 <.do_clear_bss_loop>:
  48:   1d 92           st  X+, r1

0000004a <.do_clear_bss_start>:
  4a:   a1 30           cpi r26, 0x01   ; 1
  4c:   b2 07           cpc r27, r18
  4e:   e1 f7           brne    .-8         ; 0x48 <.do_clear_bss_loop>
  50:   02 d0           rcall   .+4         ; 0x56 <main>
  52:   26 c0           rjmp    .+76        ; 0xa0 <_exit>

00000054 <__bad_interrupt>:
  54:   d5 cf           rjmp    .-86        ; 0x0 <__vectors>

00000056 <main>:

volatile uint8_t c=0;

int main(void){

    TCCR0B= (1<<CS02) | (1<<CS00);
  56:   85 e0           ldi r24, 0x05   ; 5
  58:   85 bd           out 0x25, r24   ; 37
    TIMSK0= (1<<TOIE0);
  5a:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
  5c:   80 93 6e 00     sts 0x006E, r24
    sei();
  60:   78 94           sei
    DDRD= 1<<1;
  62:   82 e0           ldi r24, 0x02   ; 2
  64:   8a b9           out 0x0a, r24   ; 10

    while (1){
        if( c>5 ) { cli(); }
  66:   80 91 00 01     lds r24, 0x0100
  6a:   86 30           cpi r24, 0x06   ; 6
  6c:   e0 f3           brcs    .-8         ; 0x66 <main+0x10>
  6e:   f8 94           cli
  70:   fa cf           rjmp    .-12        ; 0x66 <main+0x10>

00000072 <__vector_16>:
    }
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect){
  72:   1f 92           push    r1
  74:   0f 92           push    r0
  76:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  78:   0f 92           push    r0
  7a:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  7c:   8f 93           push    r24
  7e:   9f 93           push    r25
    c++;
  80:   80 91 00 01     lds r24, 0x0100
  84:   8f 5f           subi    r24, 0xFF   ; 255
  86:   80 93 00 01     sts 0x0100, r24
    PORTD ^= 1<<1;
  8a:   9b b1           in  r25, 0x0b   ; 11
  8c:   82 e0           ldi r24, 0x02   ; 2
  8e:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  90:   8b b9           out 0x0b, r24   ; 11
  92:   9f 91           pop r25
  94:   8f 91           pop r24
  96:   0f 90           pop r0
  98:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
  9a:   0f 90           pop r0
  9c:   1f 90           pop r1
  9e:   18 95           reti

000000a0 <_exit>:
  a0:   f8 94           cli

000000a2 <__stop_program>:
  a2:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0xa2 <__stop_program>
```

Comment: What the blink rate should be, and what the blink rate is? Have you got wachdog enaled which periodically resets the AVR so it keeps blinking?

Comment: Is the watchdog timer enabled?

Comment: @Tom Carpenter watchdog is disabled.

Comment: @Justme blink rate should be correct as configured by cs bits. watchdog is disabled. using the default fuses.

Comment: Did you try to stop the timer instead of disabling the interrupts? -- However, I see no obvious problem in your code.